# Check if object has particular property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an array of objects

```
const arr = [ {name:"Bob", age: 20}, { name: "Sara", age: 22}, { name:
Tom, age:20} ];
```

I want to print objects with particular property, for example only those with the age == 20. So The result would be

```
const arr = [ {name:"Bob", age: 20}, { name: Tom, age:20} ];
```

I really want to do it with ES6. Do you have any suggestion what method could be used?

Comment: `arr.filter(x => x.age == 20)`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do

```
var filteredData = arr.filter((e) => e.age === 20)
```

Comment: could you explain a bit how it does the trick?

Comment: filter() is a function available on Array now. It iterates the complete array and returns the value which is matching the condition. In above case age==20.
=> function from ES6 provides a short cut here...so that you do not need to explicitly 'return' the value. It will do it automatically (if you have only one line of code inside it).

Comment: For more detail and example, you can read it on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example

Comment: I meant explain in the answer, but never mind, closed as duplicate